# Convert char pointer to unsigned char array

Tags: c

I want to convert a char pointer to a unsigned char var, I thought I could do that with just casting but it doesn't work:

```
char * pch2;
//Code that puts something in pc2
part1 = (unsigned char) pch2;
```

I've the code to this:

```
result.part1 = (unsigned char *) pch2;
printf("STRUCT %s\n",result.part1);
```

result is just a struct with unsigned char arrays.

EDIT:

```
            pch2 = strtok( ip, "." );

            while( pch2 != NULL ){
                printf( "x %d x: %s\n", i, pch2 );
                pch2[size-1] = '\0';

                if(i == 1)
                    result.part1 = (unsigned char *) pch2;
                if(i == 2)
                    result.part2 = (unsigned char *) pch2;
                if(i == 3)
                    result.part3 = (unsigned char *) pch2;
                if(i == 4)
                    result.part4 = (unsigned char *) pch2;
                i++;
                pch2 = strtok (NULL,".");
            }   
            printf("STRUCT %c\n",result.part1);
```

Struct:

```
typedef struct
{
    unsigned char part1;
    unsigned char part2;
    unsigned char part3;
    unsigned char part4;
} res;
```

Comment: In your title you ask for an array, in your text for a variable and most of the answers are showing you how to get a pointer to unsigned char. Which is it?

Comment: I'm having a pointer that I want to convert to a unsigned char array?

Answer (score 3):

you cast to `unsigned char` not `unsigned char*` you forgot the `*`

```
part1 = (unsigned char*) pch2;
```

if `pch2` is not null terminated the program will crash, if you're lucky, when you use `strlen`, so you need to null terminate it first before printing using `pch2`, try this instead:

```
pch2[size-1] = '\0';  /* note single quote */
result.part1 = (unsigned char *) pch2;
```

Update: define your structure like so:

```
typedef struct
{
    const char *part1;
    const char *part2
    const char *part3;
    const char *part4;
} res;
```

And assign to it without casting at all:

```
result.part1 = pch2;
```

Comment: when printing out like a string the program stops running?

Comment: @user1007522 C strings should be null terminated strings of `char` not unsigned characters, what are you trying to do exactly ?

Comment: @user1007522: you can print a single char using `%c`. For example: `printf("STRUCT %c\n", *result.part1);`

Comment: Thanks when using %c it works like a charm. Do I need a for loop then to print everything?

Comment: @user1007522 no, you need to `NULL` terminate the string `pch2[size-1]=0`

Comment: @mux that's probably the same, the basic character set should fit both in `signed` and `unsigned` `char` since it's unspecified if plain `char` is `signed` or `unsigned`.

Comment: If you want to print a C string (null terminated array of char), you don't need a loop, instead use %s, the printf will start printing from the character you pointed up to the first null character it finds. But if you just have a bunch of separate chars, then yeah, you might need a loop.

Comment: I've edited the code, I added a \0 and still it just crashes. The first pch2 print works like a charm so I thought that the string was good.

Comment: @user1007522 updated my answer, if that doesn't help you should show us how you read `pch2`

Comment: It does, but If I can't use strlen to know the length of the char how can I nullterminate it then? I will put the whole code in edit ..

Comment: check my edit code. ( I've wrote size but that must be something else.. like strlen but It can't .. )

Comment: @user1007522 I see, no you don't need to null terminate strings returned from `strtok` are null terminated, do you initialize i ? `i=1` before the loop ?

Comment: @user1007522 you should use `%s` to print the string not `%c` other than that I see no reason it shouldn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You want to do this:

```
part1 = (unsigned char*) pch2;
```

Instead of:

```
part1 = (unsigned char) pch2;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:-

```
 char *ph2;
 unsigned char *new_pointer = (unsigned char*) ph2;
```

Comment: I've done that, but when doing a printf %s the program stops? Is it something with strtok because pch2 is init by strtok ?

Comment: You can try with printf("STRUCT %c\n",result.part1);

Answer (score 1):

> I want to convert a char pointer to a unsigned char var

Are you sure? Converting pointer to char to unsigned char is not going to do any good - value will get truncated to 1 byte, and it will be meaningless anyway. Maybe you want to *dereference* a pointer and get value pointed by it - then you should do something like this:

```
unsigned char part1 = (unsigned char)*pch2;
```

After your edit I see that `part1` is character array - if your program crashes after it is used, you probably fill `pch2` incorrectly. Maybe you forgot `'\0'` terminator?

EDIT:

You see, it is much better now to answer your question having all required information. Do you need to use `strtok`? Would this be good?

```
    res result;
    char* ip = "123.23.56.33";

    sscanf(ip, "%hhu.%hhu.%hhu.%hhu", &result.part1, &result.part2, &result.part3, &result.part4);
```

Comment: I think this is closer to what the OP is looking for than the answers to date, but I'm still not sure the OP has been clear yet.

Comment: I've edited the code, I terminated the char array, like you see the first print of pch2 works like a charm. The last one not :(

Comment: crucial point here is - what is pointed by `pch2` and how it gets there. Without knowing this, we cannot tell whether it is constructed correctly. Your way of terminating string is incorrect - `"\0"` *definitely* is not what should be there, and anyway you are calling `strlen` on potentially incorrect string. We need to know what value `pch2` points to.

Comment: No, I can use sscanf, but the code crashes when Copy your line. Also my struct is not a unsigned char * x but just unsigned char x or that doesn't matter with the adress operator.

Comment: Then it would be helpful to see what is `result` structure and its `part1`...`part4` members.

Comment: Then I would say that my method should work as expected - see code sample with names updated to your convention, but generally idea is the same. Are you sure that application crashes on `sscanf` or any place which refers to read data?

Comment: It crashes on the sscanf. But the ip buffer isn't a pointer buffer but a char array but that doesn't make the difference I think?

Comment: If only array is big enough and data does not exceed it's bounds - it should be ok. You need to make sure, that array can hold all characters of IP address AND null terminator, and also make sure that IP string is null terminated. How big is this array? How many characters has IP address stored in it? Can you check whether `sscanf` works with some literal value? When you copy exact three lines from my example, does it crash?

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem, forgot to cast the char pch2 to unsigned int and then I can printout with %u.
Code:

```
unsigned int temp;

temp = atoi(pch2);

result.part1 = temp;
printf("Struct: %u\n",result.part1);
```

Thanks for your help guys!